# HHVM extension, How to return class

Tags: hhvm

I declare method as Variant:

```
Variant HHVM_METHOD(MyClass1, get) {
Object ob;
ob.o_set(s_PropertyName1, value1, s_MyClass2 );
ob.o_set(s_PropertyName1, value2, s_MyClass2 );
return Variant(ob);
}
```

PHP code:

```
$c = new MyClass1();
var_dump($c->get()); // return StdClass
```

How to create and return MyClass2:

```
var_dump($c->get()); // must return MyClass2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the `Object`, you need to pass in a pointer to the `Class` object.

```cpp
Variant HHVM_METHOD(MyClass1, get) {
    Object ob{Unit::loadClass(s_MyClass2.get()};
    ob.o_set(s_PropertyName1, value1, s_MyClass2 );
    ob.o_set(s_PropertyName1, value2, s_MyClass2 );
    return ob;
}
```

You can see this being used in [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/master/hphp/runtime/ext/datetime/ext_datetime.cpp#L135-L152)